# Qual é a função do vetor (array)?

Tags: array, algoritmo, terminologia, estrutura-de-dados, portugol

Estou estudando algoritmos com Portugol e já sei usar essa estrutura. Estou tendo dificuldade para entender qual é a função do vetor no código.

Comment: Não entendi direito se você está com uma duvida em uma função chamada "vetor", ou no uso de vetores em si. Porem, isso pode lhe ajudar: http://www.dicasdeprogramacao.com.br/o-que-sao-vetores-e-matrizes-arrays/

Comment: Estou com duvida na parte explicativa, pra que serve, como pode ajudar no código. Entendeu ?

Comment: Guardar uma coleção de dados em apenas um lugar. Tipo, vc pode puxar os dados cadastrais de 50 clientes em apenas um vetor e depois ir percorrendo ele para exibir o que quiser sem precisar fazer uma nova consulta ao banco de dados por exemplo. É essa a dúvida?

Comment: Ah sim, entendi. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Um [vetor](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arranjo_(computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)) costuma ser uma variável que pode **conter vários valores** (pode ser apenas um objeto não armazenado em variável).

Você usa ele quando precisa armazenar na memória uma sequência de valores. Em geral esses valores diferentes representam a mesma coisa e é muito comum serem do mesmo tipo. Algumas linguagens até exigem que sejam do mesmo tipo, portanto, que todos sejam inteiros, ou todos sejam do tipo caractere (se forem diferentes eles precisam ser pro referência, senão não tem como ser um vetor).

Tecnicamente cada um dos elementos do vetor acaba sendo uma variável também. Então podemos dizer que um vetor é uma **coleção de variáveis**. Essas variáveis são chamadas índices.

Cada um dos elementos ou itens, como são chamados, são acessados através do índice, normalmente numérico indicando a sua posição na sequência. Ele pode ser acessado por um literal (um número) ou por uma outra variável que indique o número da posição, ou ainda uma expressão que calcule esse número.

Quando declaramos um vetor estamos reservando um espaço na memória para quantidade de elementos que ele comportará. Então em um vetor de 10 elementos de um tipo inteiro costuma alocar, a grosso modo, 40 bytes (10 x 4 bytes do tamanho do inteiro).

Um vetor é uma forma especializada de [matriz](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matriz_(matem%C3%A1tica)) que todos aprendemos na matemática. Podemos dizer que um vetor é uma única linha ou uma única coluna de uma matriz.

O funcionamento exato pode variar de linguagem para linguagem. Algumas são mais flexíveis. Algumas podem ter perda de performance. Em Portugol isto não é importante.

Dependendo da linguagem pode haver uma definição mais específica. Algumas diferenciam o *array* do *vector*, da *matrix*, da *list*, etc. Outras usam estes termos de forma intercambiável ou usam termos mais específicos para alguma variação do vetor. O Portugol usa a definição mais simples, para quem está aprendendo não é interessante entender todas as nuances.

Pense que você tem 50 notas de alunos, poderia fazer isto:

```
leia(nota1)
leia(nota2)
leia(nota3)
.
.
.
leia(nota50)
```

Complicado fazer isto, né? Poderia simplificar, automatizar a repetição. Como acessar cada uma delas? Como generalizar tudo isto? Usando o vetor:

```
leia(nota[1])
leia(nota[2])
leia(nota[3])
.
.
.
leia(nota[50])
```

Agora já tem um vetor, uma mudança simples, mas o código ainda está ruim:

```
para i de 1 ate 50 faca
    leia(nota[i])
fimpara
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Portugol/Array.ptg).

Desta forma 50 linhas se transformaram em 3. Ele faz a mesma coisa automatizada. Usa a matemática e o controle de fluxo para obter o mesmo resultado em um código simples e enxuto.

Comment: Eu posso usar vetor para armazenar as notas dos alunos, em um programa que calcule as medias dos alunos e depois exibir-las ?

Comment: Sim, pode, é uma das funções dele.

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda. É que essa parte de vetores eu achei um pouco chatinha de entender.

Comment: É pura matemática. Não tem nada novo na computação.

Answer (score 1):

De forma simples, um vetor é muito parecido com uma array.

A diferença é que o vetor geralmente tem o tamanho pré definido no momento da declaração, por exemplo:

int meuVetor[10];

Nesse caso, meuVetor só terá 10 posições, você pode manipular o que já existe, mas não pode criar novas posições. Caso tente acessar a 11ª posição vai dar erro.

Em contra partida, uma array é igual o vetor, mas sem tamanho definido, você pode criar uma array, e ir acrescentando novas posições, manipular elas, deletar etc.

Do ponto de vista de utilização, o vetor é pra quando você tem certeza que só vai usar 'X' posições, e a array é para quando você não tem certeza da quantidade de posições que irá precisar.

Answer (score 0):

Um Vetor tem a função de guardar determinadas informações específicas de acordo com seu tipo de modo que possa ou esteja em forma de índice, que permite o acesso a todos ou a determinados dados usando filtros nestes índices.