# Por que o NetBeans sugere alterar uma adição de array?

Tags: java, array, netbeans

Estou iniciando meus estudos em programação com Java. Estou criando uma classe para objeto no NetBeans que alerta a seguinte mensagem:

> Array concatenado com String

Por que?

Meu código:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class PessoaGenerica {
    int idade[]
    String nome[];
    String cidade[]

    void dizerNome(){
       System.out.println ("OLá, meu nome é" + Arrays.toString(nome));
    }

    void dizerIdade(){
       System.out.println ("OLá, meu nome é" + Arrays.toString(nome));
    }

    void dizerCidade(){
       System.out.println ("OLá, meu nome é" + Arrays.toString(nome));
    }
}
```

[image: SS]

Comment: Por que você está tentando converter um vetor de inteiros em string? E não é dessa forma que se exibe um array, é usando laço de repetição.

Comment: Já que está inciando seria bom ler isto para aprender as coisas do jeito certo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101. Procure colocar seus códigos como texto, facilita pra todo mundo. Na verdade este código não faz nem perto do que você imagina. A sugestão está errada porque o código faz tão pouco sentido que o NetBeans nem entende o que deseja de fato.

Comment: A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como faz, veja o [tour]. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você e dar uma indicação que houve uma solução satisfatória. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 3):

Acho que poderia começar lendo [o que é um vetor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/124858/101).

Até faz sentido passar o vetor todo como parâmetro, mas faz pouco sentido em acessá-lo de forma direta. Normalmente acessamos os elementos dele através de um índice. Então faria sentido fazer, por exemplo `nome[0]` para o primeiro elemento do vetor, ou `nome[1]` para o segundo.

Até poderia acessar através de um variável se ela existir em algum lugar. Poderia ser um laço que vai variando para pegar todos os elementos (ainda que nesse caso tem `for` que nem precisa pegar o índice, mas isso é assunto mais avançado): `nome[i]`.

Claro que para acessar um elemento precisa ter criado ele. Nesse código está criando nada. Sequer está reservando espaço para os vetores terem elementos. O ideal é que eles fossem declarados com a quantidade máxima de elementos que ele pode suportar. Ou então usar um `ArrayList` que permite ir crescendo o número de elementos conforme a necessidade.

Ainda fica um pouco esquisito ter um vetor para `nome`, outro para `cidade` e outro para `idade`. Estas informações parecem ser correlatas e deveriam estar juntas em uma estrutura separada, e o vetor seria do tipo criado com estes membros. Não vou entrar em detalhes porque parece ser avançado para o que conhece. Mas justamente por isso deveria ir com exemplos mais simples, talvez procurar um livro que te direcione melhor cada coisa a aprender. Por enquanto tente usar vetor só para uma coisa de cada vez e espere entender melhor a criação de classes para criar vetores com informações compostas.

Na verdade observando a classe nem sei se deveria ter vetores aí. O problema pode ser este, pode ter declarado os membros da classe como vetores e nem era o que queria. Experimenta tirar os colchetes e veja o que acontece (obviamente tirar o `Arrays.toString()` também). Talvez seja o caminho mais correto. Depois que entender bem esse funcionamento, é que poderá pensar em criar vetores em outra classe. Aí não me parece que cabe bem ter vetor. Se era a intenção mesmo, acho que está aprendendo fazer do jeito errado. Não consigo imaginar porque iria querer guardar várias pessoas dentro de uma classe que tem nome que parece ser uma pessoa só.

Reforço a ideia de procurar uma forma estruturada e de qualidade de como fazer cada coisa, que ensine o básico com boa didática e sem ser receita de bolo. Eu sei que não é fácil achar, tem que tomar muito cuidado porque tem muita coisa ruim por aí. Aqui não é adequado para pedir referências sobre isto. Comece com livros conhecidos. Seja crítico com tudo. Tente fontes diferentes. Pergunte sobre dúvidas específicas para que já tem experiência. pode ser aqui, para isto o site é muito bom.