# Mostrar sequência de String digitada

Tags: java, array, string

Como mostrar os valores lidos dentro de um laço de repetição em Java? Ex:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 2; i++){
     System.out.print("Nome: ");
     String nome = tecla.nextLine();
}
```

?? <- Fazer com que os nomes lidos apareçam aqui

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Você terá que usar um *array* ([vetor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124849/101)) para que uma [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) tenha várias posições de memória indexadas. Já apreendeu matriz na escola? É basicamente uma matriz com uma dimensão só.

[image: Array index]

Então na verdade nesse exemplo temos 10 variáveis na memória que acessadas por um nome e um índice e uma variável que engloba essas variáveis que pode ser acessada pelo nome, mas sem índice não pode acessar o que está dentro dela.

Os colchetes são usados para indicar o índice que será acessado nessa variável.

O [*array* começa sempre pelo 0](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/183798/101), então mudei seu `for`.

Sem o vetor cada ciclo de repetição do `for` apagará o valor anteriormente armazenado na variável, então tem que reservar posições para todas as entradas que deseja digitar, o *array* é a solução.

Claro que em um exemplo simples assim poderia ter criado 3 variáveis e nem ter um laço, mas imagino que está querendo fazer do jeito que se faz em aplicações reais. Se fosse 100 seria só mudar o número ali. Alias isso é considerado [número mágico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135108/101), em código real, não é bom fazer assim. Mas na verdade em código real mesmo, você perguntará quantas entradas terão e alocará dinamicamente, ou usará uma lista no lugar do *array* e ir adicionando enquanto a pessoa for digitando novas entradas. Mas isso deixa pra próxima.

Dá pra melhora mais esse código, mas não vamos fazer tudo de uma vez.

```
import java.util.*;

class HelloWorld {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String[] nomes = new String[3]; //declara a variável e inicializa com 3 posições
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.print("Nome: ");
            nomes[i] = scanner.nextLine(); //armazenando em cada posição variando pelo for
            System.out.println();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) System.out.println("Nome: " + nomes[i]); //acessando cada posição
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/hzVnV9). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/teqcoayd-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Array/Simple.java).