# Em quais casos/ocasiões devo utilizar a struct em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, struct, estilo-de-codificação

`struct` é uma forma de criar novos tipo de dados dentro do C#, Personalizar novos tipos.

Basicamente `struct`s criam várias variáveis dentro de um só local, além de variáveis podem criar funções também.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Começamos dizendo que é sempre que deseja criar um tipo. Porém por que criar um tipo?

Bem, tecnicamente em C# você sempre tem que criar um tipo. Embora hoje tem algumas formas que essa criação é disfarçada e o compilador cria esse tipo para você. Você não vê no código mas por baixo dos panos o tipo está lá. Isso tem vantagens e desvantagens.

Até uma classe estática é um tipo mesmo que ela funcione apenas como um *namespace* para várias funções. Em essência você não pode ter funções soltas em C# (em C# 9 tem, mas é só *syntax sugar*, ou seja, ainda tem um tipo escondido).

Por uma definição existe um tipo [primitivo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/356647/101) nas linguagens que é o que o processador entende de forma direta. Muitas vezes o termo escalar é usado porque em geral esses tipos tem uma quantidade finita de possibilidades, é um valor que vai de tal a tal quantidade. Até quando vai falar de letras, que não deixam de ser números disfarçados, você tem uma escala permitido do que pode usar e o processador sabe operar isso.

Em contraposto existem os tipos compostos que são criados para facilitar a vida do programador e eles usam um ou mais tipos de forma singular ou repetida de forma homogênea ou heterogênea, e pode ser criado de forma [estrutural ou nominal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190463/101).

Note que apesar da forma estrutural parecer que não está criando um tipo, ele é criado, só não tem nome explicitamente definido e por isso não pode ser usado em todo o código de forma confiável, então quando você confia que o programador usará aquilo de forma correta sem um contrato formal é problema seu se algo não funcionar corretamente. Pelo menos em C# o tipo está lá sem nome. No fim falo um pouco desse tipo estrutural.

Em geral em C# por questão de robustez se prefere criar um tipo nominado para compor a junção de dados diversos para criar um entidade nova que pode ser usado por todo o código. Pelo menos é assim se aquela composição será usada ou tem potencial de ser usada em lugares diferentes do código.

Uma forma composta de forma repetida e geralmente homogênea é o [*array*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124849/101) ou outros tipos de coleções. Sempre que precisar disso use-o.

Quando precisa criar uma abstração em cima de algo que dá um novo conceito para uma ou mais informações juntas você pode criar um tipo nominado específico. Tem algumas formas diferentes de fazer isso e falo mais abaixo, vou me concentrar na `struct` aqui.

Reforço a ideia que é possível criar essa abstração para apenas um tipo primitivo, ou mesmo um já composto, sem formar uma nova composição de fato. Algo singular não deixa de ser uma composição que só tem um outro dado ali. Pode-se criar isso só pela abstração e ver vantagens em como manipular isto. É menos comum mas pode fazer.

O mais comum é ter mais de um dado, por exemplo um ponto cartesiano que tem um valor inteiro ou decimal para representar o eixo X e outro para representar o eixo Y. Essa composição forma um único objeto, o ponto cartesiano, e é composto por dois objetos primitivos numéricos básicos, que pode ser inteiro com alguma escala ou alguma forma decimal. Você pode escolher o tipo que dá melhor escala para a intenção.

Para esse ponto virar um objeto com nome, que pode ser usado em todo código apenas dizendo o nome, e a linguagem entende todos contratos que o programador determinou pode criar uma `struct`.

De fato isso é tão útil que a própria linguagem cria alguns tipos assim. Por exemplo o `DateTime`, `DateOnly`, `TimeSpan` e outros tipos de marcação de tempo foram criados assim. Nada mais são `struct`s que formam esses tipos como dados primitivos dentro desse novo tipo e contratos expressados em vários métodos de como deve manipular esse objeto. De fato você pode ver os fontes desses tipos. Vou colocar aqui [um deles](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/DateTime.cs,df6b1eba7461813b).

Na data desta postagem a linha 144 tem o único dado do objeto em si:

```
private readonly ulong _dateData;
```

Ou seja, pegaram um tipo primitivo inteiro longo o bastante para ter uma quantidade enorme de unidades pequenas de tempo e sem sinal e passaram manipular esse dado de maneiras que faça sentido em um objeto que deseja lidar como um ponto no tempo e não só um número sem muita semântica (veja todos os métodos lá). Criamos uma abstração em cima de um tipo concreto. É um tipo composto por apenas um outro dado agora com uma cara nova que dá mais significado.

Pode ver o exemplo do [`Decimal`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Decimal.cs,1b2858baf311cbf9) que é composto por 3 dados de tipos diferentes para formar um valor decimal capaz de tudo o que esse tipo se propõe fazer.

E você pode criar seus próprios tipos sempre que tiver um valor que mereça uma abstração. Pode ser para um telefone. Se não fizer isto está incorrendo no *antipattern* chamado Primitive Obsession. Se o fizer incorrerá no *Abstraction Obsession*, escolha seu veneno. Ok, se fizer o mais adequado não tem obsessão alguma, o problema ocorre quando faz por fazer, sem necessidade.

Os próprios tipos básicos da linguagem acabam tendo uma `struct` para representá-los, mas cuidado porque essas estruturas são manipuladas de forma especial pelo compilador, o `int`, que é um apelido para o tipo [`Int32`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Int32.cs,225942ed7b7a3252) não é formado ali no código fonte da biblioteca, ela existe para dar funções (métodos) extras para uso com o tipo. Então cuidado para avaliar esses tipos primitivos.

Com essa ressalva olhe a [documentação do .NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-7.0#structs) (pode ver de outros *namespaces* também) para se acostumar com algumas estruturas já prontas e ter ideias de quando é útil usar este mecanismo.

Vou dar um exemplo de uma `struct` que dependendo do que se deseja poderia ser uma classe. A maiorias das `struct`s mais claras são objetos mais simples, são mais abstrações simples como os exemplos acima e na documentação. Note que o caso a seguir pode ser mais útil até mesmo como um `ref struct` ou um `record struct`, depende de como será usado, só dentro de uma classe é ok a estrutura simples, mas de forma bem simplificada, sem fazer algo bem feito que faça sentido:

```
struct Endereco {
    public string TipoLogradouro;
    public string Logradouro;
    public string Numero;
    public string Complemento;
    public string Bairro;
    public string Cidade;
    public string Uf;
    public string Cep;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Struct/Example.cs).

Então uma `struct` foi criada para dar [coesão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101) a uma informação que  é única mas composta por várias outras.

Criar um tipo de forma adequada é mais complexo do que isso e exige planejamento, exige documentar bem, pelo código real mesmo, exige pensar sobre todos detalhes de sua utilização. Nesse exemplo poderia ter várias validações, ter feito os métodos que todo tipo precisa ter e que ele recebeu por herança mas de forma ineficiente. Sem esse detalhamento e pensamento todo não tem porque criar um tipo, joga em qualquer outro lugar *não estruturado*.

Minha crítica a uso de linguagens que preferem a forma pouco estruturada é que se você tentar estruturar muito está usando a ferramenta errada, claramente é algo deficiente para aquilo, ou então você está fazendo tudo na base do "bumba meu boi". Só é mais produtivo usar linguagens com menos formalização se você fizer do segundo jeito.

Quando o programador preza pela produtividade de curto prazo, ou usa o método "bumba meu boi" de programação fazer tudo isso corretamente é perda de tempo e ele deveria usar uma linguagem mais simples de tipagem dinâmica. Fazer a estrutura de código correta, bem pensada dá muito mais trabalho no começo, mas pode poupar trabalho futuro dando mais legibilidade, expressividade, robustez, sem falar em eficiência, mas isso vem depois de pagar o custo inicial. A tipagem correta te obriga a pensar mais sobre o problema e tende produzir melhores resultados.

## Comparando com outras opções

Embora muitas pessoas pensem o contrário eu diria que sempre que precisar criar um tipo deve optar pela `struct` por padrão.

E aí vem a pegadinha que faz muitas pessoas acharem o contrário. Na maioria das vezes não escolherá ela. Isso não quer dizer que não deveria ser a escolha padrão, pelo menos para criar um tipo. Ela é mais simples e eficiente que outras formas.

Uma classe permite herança, aloca no *heap*, é por referência que causa alguma complicação, tem gerenciamento mais complicado, costuma ser mutável, tem algumas exigências de como funciona, então deveria ser evitado tanto quanto possível.

Mesmo que seja necessário apenas ser por referência por eficiência tem a `ref struct` que pode ser usada de forma limitada.

Melhor ainda se usar a `readonly struct` (pode ser `ref` também) porque em geral as `struct`s deveriam ser [imutáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101).

Mais recentemente temos a estrutura de registro ([`record struct`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/539114/101)) que talvez deva ser até a preferência, mas ainda não usei o suficiente para ter certeza que é a melhor opção. Certamente será melhor usá-la em vários casos, ela já resolve de forma mais eficiente e fácil alguns casos que exigiria o programador fazer na mão o mesmo.

O `record` veio para dar um pouco de produtividade sem perder a flexibilidade e eficiência (esses dias vi uma celebridade de internet na área falando sobre `record` ser ineficiente, mas foi o jeito errado de usar, ela não testou, só acreditou em um erro de outra pessoa postado em blog, o que mina toda credibilidade dela).

O uso adequado depende de experiência. Não tem fórmula mágica. Por isso escolher suas referências e ter alguém bom que faz boas escolhas para ir te orientando e indicando o certo pode ser fundamental, pelo menos em parte. Ver o que os outros estão fazendo para criar seu estilo é muito útil na falta de apoio mais direto.

Outro ponto que eu não abordei e não estou querendo detalhar muito a comparação com outras opções, é usar a tupla. A tupla não deixa de ser um tipo, mas funciona como um tipo anônimo, e de certa forma ela deveria ser a preferência. Aqui se torna um pouco mais complicado, mas é um ponto interessante porque em alguns casos criar um tipo específico nominado é exagero. Quando deseja apenas juntar dados circunstancialmente para uma operação isolada a tupla se torna mais adequada, ou seja, pra que criar uma entidade no seu código para algo tão simples e pontual?

[Veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101).